# Python Iteration using while loops and a timer

Tags: python, while-loop, timer, pygame, iteration

I am trying to run my program with a timer so that it will stop after 10 seconds but having problems with my iterating through it, so far I've tried using 2 while loops and a while loop within a for loop but have not come right. The program essentially makes shapes fall from top to bottom of the screen but I want it to stop after 10 seconds.

```
def main():
    star = pygame.Rect(75, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    triangle = pygame.Rect(575, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    rectangle = pygame.Rect(175, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    square = pygame.Rect(275, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    hexagon = pygame.Rect(375, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    circle = pygame.Rect(475, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    for i in range (10,0,-1):
        time.sleep(1)
        run = True
        while run:
            if star.y > HEIGHT:
                star.y = -1
            elif triangle.y > HEIGHT:
                triangle.y = -1
            elif rectangle.y > HEIGHT:
                rectangle.y = -1
            elif square.y > HEIGHT:
                square.y = -1
            elif hexagon.y > HEIGHT:
                hexagon.y = -1
            elif circle.y > HEIGHT:
                circle.y = -1

    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           run = False
    star.y += 2
    triangle.y += 2
    rectangle.y += 2
    square.y += 2
    hexagon.y += 2
    circle.y += 2
    draw_window_one(star, triangle, rectangle, square, hexagon, circle)

    pygame.quit()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: The `while run:` loop will run forever, because there is no code inside the loop to change `run` to false.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to stop after 10 seconds, consider a comparison

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import sys
import time


start = datetime.now()

while datetime.now() - start < timedelta(seconds=10):
    # your thing
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    sys.stdout.write(f"{datetime.now() - start}")
```